# Direct2D draws nothing on a "hardware mode" render target

Tags: winapi, directx, direct3d, direct2d

I 'm trying to use Direct2D on a render target created by Direct3D according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/direct2d-and-direct3d-interoperation-overview) MSDN document. The idea not to use a HWND render buffer is for the application to be able to switch targets easily, so I can e.g. render to a bitmap the static painting and use direct commands for any runtime-dependent painting. The code to create the interfaces is the following:

```
bool CreateD2DC(HWND hh)
{
    D2D& d = *this;
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevels[] =
    {
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_2,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1
    };
    auto de = D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE;
    if (IsCurrentSessionRemoteable())
        de = D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_SOFTWARE;
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL m_featureLevel;
    D3D11CreateDevice(
        nullptr,                    // specify null to use the default adapter
        de,
        0,
        D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT,              // optionally set debug and Direct2D compatibility flags
        featureLevels,              // list of feature levels this app can support
        ARRAYSIZE(featureLevels),   // number of possible feature levels
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
        &d.device,                // returns the Direct3D device created
        &m_featureLevel,            // returns feature level of device created
        &d.context                    // returns the device immediate context
    );
    if (!d.device)
        return 0;

    d.dxgiDevice = d.device;
    if (!d.dxgiDevice)
        return 0;

    D2D1_CREATION_PROPERTIES dp;
    dp.threadingMode = D2D1_THREADING_MODE::D2D1_THREADING_MODE_SINGLE_THREADED;
    dp.debugLevel = D2D1_DEBUG_LEVEL::D2D1_DEBUG_LEVEL_NONE;
    dp.options = D2D1_DEVICE_CONTEXT_OPTIONS::D2D1_DEVICE_CONTEXT_OPTIONS_NONE;
    D2D1CreateDevice(d.dxgiDevice, dp, &d.m_d2dDevice);
    if (!d.m_d2dDevice)
        return 0;

    d.m_d2dDevice->CreateDeviceContext(
        D2D1_DEVICE_CONTEXT_OPTIONS_NONE,
        &d.m_d2dContext);
    if (!d.m_d2dContext)
        return 0;

    // Allocate a descriptor.
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC1 swapChainDesc = { 0 };
    swapChainDesc.Width = 0;                           // use automatic sizing
    swapChainDesc.Height = 0;
    swapChainDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM; // this is the most common swapchain format
    swapChainDesc.Stereo = false;
    swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;                // don't use multi-sampling
    swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    swapChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    swapChainDesc.BufferCount = 2;                     // use double buffering to enable flip
    swapChainDesc.Scaling = DXGI_SCALING_NONE;
    swapChainDesc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_SEQUENTIAL; // all apps must use this SwapEffect
    swapChainDesc.Flags = 0;

    d.dxgiDevice->GetAdapter(&d.dxgiAdapter);
    if (!d.dxgiAdapter)
        return 0;

    // Get the factory object that created the DXGI device.
    d.dxgiAdapter->GetParent(IID_PPV_ARGS(&d.dxgiFactory));
    if (!d.dxgiFactory)
        return 0;

    d.dxgiFactory->CreateSwapChainForHwnd(
        d.device,
        hh, &swapChainDesc,
        nullptr,    // allow on all displays
        nullptr,    // allow on all displays
        &d.m_swapChain);
    if (!d.m_swapChain)
        return 0;

    d.dxgiDevice->SetMaximumFrameLatency(1);

    d.m_swapChain->GetBuffer(0, IID_PPV_ARGS(&d.backBuffer));
    if (!d.backBuffer)
        return 0;

    // Now we set up the Direct2D render target bitmap linked to the swapchain. 
    D2D1_BITMAP_PROPERTIES1 bitmapProperties;
    bitmapProperties.bitmapOptions = D2D1_BITMAP_OPTIONS_TARGET | D2D1_BITMAP_OPTIONS_CANNOT_DRAW;
    bitmapProperties.pixelFormat.alphaMode = D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE;
    bitmapProperties.pixelFormat.format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
    bitmapProperties.dpiX = 96;
    bitmapProperties.dpiY = 96;
    bitmapProperties.colorContext = 0;


    // Direct2D needs the dxgi version of the backbuffer surface pointer.
    d.m_swapChain->GetBuffer(0, IID_PPV_ARGS(&d.dxgiBackBuffer));
    if (!d.dxgiBackBuffer)
        return 0;

    // Get a D2D surface from the DXGI back buffer to use as the D2D render target.
    d.m_d2dContext->CreateBitmapFromDxgiSurface(
        d.dxgiBackBuffer,
        &bitmapProperties,
        &d.m_d2dTargetBitmap);
    if (!d.m_d2dTargetBitmap)
        return 0;


    // Now we can set the Direct2D render target.
    d.m_d2dContext->SetTarget(d.m_d2dTargetBitmap);
    return true;
}
```

The problem is this code:

```
auto de = D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE;
```

When used, Direct2D writes nothing although `EndDraw()` returns S_OK. If I use `D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_SOFTWARE`, everything works correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Error checking is all wrong. You should check `HRESULT` return value.

Comment: Show more information about your test environment like Windows version, SDK version etc. A mini, complete and reproducible sample is helpful for looking into this issue.